# Checking with MySQL whether the number of rows of a table is less than (N + 8)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a check I'm trying to run for whether the number of rows in a table is less than N+8. The reason it's very messy is because I have to use the WordPress API and `get_results` function (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) to get everything from MySQL land to PHP land.

What I have is

```
$stillSomeLeft = ($wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $thisTable < (%d  + 8)", $_POST['numItemsLoaded']))) === true;
```

and `$stillSomeLeft` is always evaluating to `false`. Of course, since `get_results` returns an object corresponding to the result of the query, I have no way of knowing exactly what that object will be, but since the query would return `true`/`false` in MySQL land, I assume the PHP equivalent "object" will be the same.

Gotta love loosely-typed languages ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the select statement

You only need

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $thisTable
```

With that value you compare to N + 8 in your PHP.

Comment: I'm not sure what `get_results` returns for that query, but I know that when I convert the result to JSON it becomes `[{"COUNT(*)":"17"}]`. Weird.

Comment: if you run that query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $thisTable` on mysql you also get 17? Because that looks like a correct result